# flask_restful : Unable perform a POST operation > Error code : 500 internal server error

Tags: flask, flask-restful

I am new to flask and learning it through a series of tutorials.
I am trying to create simple endpoints (GET, POST). But unable to perform POST method itself.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
# api = Api(app)

items = []

# class Item(Resource):
#     def get(self, name):
#         for item in items:
#             if item['name'] == name:
#                 return item
#         return {'item' : None} , 404
#
#     def post(self, name):
#         item = {'name' : name, 'price' : 12.00}
#         items.append(item)
#         return item , 201
#
# api.add_resource(Item, '/item/<string:name>/')

@app.route('/item/<string:name>/')
def get(name):
    for item in items:
        if item['name'] == name:
            return jsonify(item)
    return jsonify({'item' : None})

@app.route('/item/<string:name>', methods=['POST'])
def post(self, name):
    item = {'name' : name, 'price' : 12.00}
    items.append(item)
    return item

app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: The dict `items` doesn't exist in your `post` function, i.e. you're trying to append `item` to something that isn't there.

Comment: Yes, it is because I intend to create an object (item) from POST **/item/<string:name>** request and append it.
Am I making any mistake in it?

Comment: The line `items.append(item)` will cause an error because `items` doesn't exist. You'll need to remove this line or add `items = {}` before this line.

Comment: Actually I  have to add the item I will be getting from the POST method to `items` list in the form of dictionaries. Will it work if I declare it as a Global variable in my class?

Comment: Sorry, missed `items` as a global variable, that's not great practice, think about using a database if you want to persist data between requests. Your "GET" method is using `jsonify` to create a Response object, is this missing from your "POST" method? i.e. `return jsonify(item)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. Creating a database worked out well.